# Rails Scaffold Index Filtering

Tags: ruby, html, css, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a CAD app (Rails 4, Ruby 2.2). On the Calls index Page I have 2 panels side by side.

My goal is to sort the panels into Active and Unassigned based on a DB attribute, which is currently names Status and is a "string"

I'm just not sure how to do this at all I've tried to search it out with not much luck. I am using Postgresql as my DB and below is the code for the index page I have not modified my controller but i will add the code for reference.

**Index.html.erb code:**

```
  <div class="panel panel-success" id="active-pnl">
    <div class="panel-heading"><center><h4>Assigned Calls: </h4></center></div>
    <table class="table" id="assign-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><center>Call Number</center></th>
          <th><center>Address</center></th>
          <th><center>Responding</center></th>
          <th><center>Call Type</center></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <% @calls.each do |call| %>
        <tr>
          <td><center><%= call.call_num %></center></td>
          <td><center><%= call.address %></center></td>
          <td><center><strong><%= call.unit_1 %></strong> | <%= call.unit_2 %> | <%= call.unit_3 %> | <%= call.unit_4 %></center></td>
          <td><center><%= call.primary_type %> | <%= call.secondary_type %></center></td>
          <td><center><%= link_to 'View', call, class: 'btn btn-success btn-sm', id: 'view-btn' %></center></td>
          <td><center><%= link_to 'Update', edit_call_path(call), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm', id: 'update-btn' %></center></td>
          <td><center><%= link_to 'Cancel', call, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-sm', id: 'cancel-btn', method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></center></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-danger" id="unactive-pnl">
  <div class="panel-heading"><center><h4>Unassigned Calls:</h4></center></div>
    <table class="table" id="nonassign-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><center>Call Number</center></th>
          <th><center>Address</center></th>
          <th><center>Status</center></th>
          <th><center>Call Type</center></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <% @calls.each do |call| %>
        <tr>
          <td><center><%= call.call_num %></center></td>
          <td><center><%= call.address %></center></td>
          <td><center><%= call.status %></center></td>
          <td><center><%= call.primary_type %> | <%= call.secondary_type %></center></td>
          <td><center><%= link_to 'View', call, class: 'btn btn-success btn-sm', id: 'view-btn' %></center></td>
          <td><center><%= link_to 'Update', edit_call_path(call), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm', id: 'update-btn' %></center></td>
          <td><center><%= link_to 'Cancel', call, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-sm', id: 'cancel-btn', method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></center></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>



<br>
<center>
  <%= link_to new_call_path, class: "btn btn-success btn-lg", id: 'newcall-btn' do %>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"> NewCall</i>
  <% end %>
</center>
```

**Calls Controller:**

```
class CallsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_call, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /calls
  # GET /calls.json
  def index
    @calls = Call.all
  end

  # GET /calls/1
  # GET /calls/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /calls/new
  def new
    @call = Call.new
  end

  # GET /calls/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /calls
  # POST /calls.json
  def create
    @call = Call.new(call_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @call.save
        format.html { redirect_to @call, notice: 'Call was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @call }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @call.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /calls/1
  # PATCH/PUT /calls/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @call.update(call_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @call, notice: 'Call was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @call }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @call.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /calls/1
  # DELETE /calls/1.json
  def destroy
    @call.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to calls_url, notice: 'Call was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_call
      @call = Call.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def call_params
      params.require(:call).permit(:call_time, :status, :primary_type, :secondary_type, :site, :address, :unit_1, :unit_2, :unit_3, :unit_4, :call_details, :unit_on_scene, :unit_clear, :call_num, :site_id)
    end
end
```

So to recap: I am looking for something that will sort the calls into either of the tables based on its current status. If ACTIVE i would like it in the Active calls Table if Unassigned i would like it in the unassigned table. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have two values 1 and 0 in the field status of model Call. In your controller action:

```
def index
    @active_calls = Call.where(status: 1)
    @inactive_calls = Call.where(status: 0)
end
```

Then you can access two arrays @active_calls and @inactive_calls in your view, just replaces

```
<% @calls.each do |call| %>
```

to

```
<% @active_calls.each do |call| %>
```

or

```
<% @inactive_calls.each do |call| %>
```

based on where you would like to display them.

Comment: So i should then change the column to an integer value? or just use a select field and set the values to 1 and 0 when sending to the DB?

Comment: No, you don't need to change the column in DB. If your column is string, it is okay as well. Just give the value there. For example, if your values are "active" and "inactive", just change it to @active_calls = Call.where(status: "active")

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response works great!!! Really appreciate the assistance!